# Why do my tests junit cucumber test fail when run together, but pass individually, throwing a no such ID session on the 2nd test?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

New to cucumber, both my scenarios work fine but when I run them both, the 2nd one fails. The first one runs fine and then closes the browser, then starts the browser again the 2nd scenario fails after opening up the browser and a couple steps in it throws a Invalid session id.

I tried changing the chrome driver, but It still does not work.
Any idea on why this is happening?

I updated the chrome exe file to match with the 76 version chrome browser I have. I updated it in the TestBase class and in the Main project.

Feature: Jira HomePage Test

- Verify Home Page title and then create a story under project Shop4NASA.
- Verify the story was created  under Shop4NASA.
- Put the story in ready, in progress, test, done, and close state and verify it.
- Create Comment and attach screen shots for this story.
- Create a Bug, and put into ready, inprogress, test, done and close state and verify it.
- Create Comment and attach screen shots for this bug.

Background:

Given User is on Jira homepage
Then  User verifies homepage title of Jira Page
When  User clicks on projects and QA Upgrade Test

## This is Test Case 002 in JIRA  -Create Epic issue and go through workflow To Do->In Progress->Done->Closed->To Do

```
     @End2End 
     Scenario: Create Epic
           


               When  User clicks on create for an EPIC
               And   User fills out the asterick fields of EPIC
               And   User clicks Create
               When  User clicks on EPIC 
               Then  User verifies EPIC was created
               And   User clicks on inprogress  
               Then  User verifies Status is inprogress
               When  User clicks on Done
               Then  User verifies Status is Done
               When  User clicks on Close
               Then  User verifies Status is Closed
```

## Epic Name on CreateissuePage line 130, line 163 is the summary, on homepagedef check line 132

## Story summary is on create issue page line 136 and descirption is one 143. and on homepage def story check line 170 to change every time we run

```
#Test Case ID 003: JIRA  -Create Story issue and go through workflow To Do-> Ready>In Progress->Ready for testing> Testing> Done->Closed->To Do               
     @End2End   
     Scenario: Create Story  
   
               When  User clicks on create for an Story
               And   User fills out the asterick fields of Story
               And   User clicks Create
               When  User clicks on Story 
               Then  User verifies Story was created
               When  User clicks on To Do
               Then  User verifies Status is To Do
               When  User clicks on Ready 
               Then  User verifies Status is Ready  
               And   User clicks on inprogress for story  
               Then  User verifies Status is inprogress
               When  User clicks on Ready for Test
               Then  User verifies Status is Ready for Test
               When  User clicks on Testing 
               Then  User verifies Status is Testing                
               When  User clicks on WorkFlow Done
               Then  User verifies Status is DONE
               When  User clicks on Close button
               Then  User verifies Status is Closed


@And("^User fills out the asterick fields of Story$")
    public void userFillsOutTheAsterickFieldsOfStory() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete 
   actions
     homePage = new HomePage(driver);
     createIssuePage = new CreateIssuePage(driver);
      
        createIssuePage.clickIssueType();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        createIssuePage.clickCreateStoryIssueType();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        createIssuePage.fillStorySummary();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        createIssuePage.fillStoryDescription();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
```

Fails on User fills out the asterick fields of Story

```
Starting ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}) on port 30443
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Oct 08, 2019 4:53:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake create Session
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
10-08-2019 16:53:41 INFO  TestBase:43 - Chrome browser is invoked
10-08-2019 16:53:42 INFO  TestBase:74 - Driver is returned 
ReadProperties - url:  https://j*****
10-08-2019 16:53:47 INFO  HomePage:120 - JIRA HomePage constructor is invoked
10-08-2019 16:53:50 INFO  HomePage:126 - JIRA Home Page Title is returned
Were on Home page of Jira Stage and the title is: System Dashboard - JIRA Stage
10-08-2019 16:53:50 INFO  HomePage:133 - Clicking on the Project Tab
10-08-2019 16:53:50 INFO  HomePage:152 - Clicking on the QA Test Project 2 (QTP2) link
10-08-2019 16:53:53 INFO  HomePage:157 - Clicking on the Create Button
10-08-2019 16:53:53 INFO  CreateIssuePage:60 - Create Issue Page constructor is invoked
10-08-2019 16:53:56 INFO  CreateIssuePage:117 - JIRA Create Issue Page Title is returned
Were on Create Issue Page of QAT project and the title is: Create Issue - JIRA Stage
10-08-2019 16:53:56 INFO  HomePage:120 - JIRA HomePage constructor is invoked
10-08-2019 16:53:56 INFO  CreateIssuePage:60 - Create Issue Page constructor is invoked
10-08-2019 16:53:56 INFO  CreateIssuePage:123 - Clicking on the dropdown
10-08-2019 16:53:56 INFO  HomePageStepDefinition:43 - Completed executing scenario : Create Story
 ------------------ runAfterScenario ------------------  : Status: Failed
 ***HomePageStepDefinition - runAfterScenario ***  :Take screenshot
10-08-2019 16:53:57 INFO  HomePageStepDefinition:61 - C:\Users\a\eclipse-workspace\Ji\target\surefire-reports\Screenshots\Failed\Create Story-10-08-2019-16-53-57.png
10-08-2019 16:53:57 INFO  TestBase:69 - Driver is closed

[31mFailed scenarios:[0m
[31msrc/test/java/com/nasa/jira/feature/jira.feature:39 [0m# Scenario: Create Story

2 Scenarios ([31m1 failed[0m, [32m1 passed[0m)
36 Steps ([31m1 failed[0m, [36m17 skipped[0m, [32m18 passed[0m)
1m18.872s

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'H', ip: '156', misname: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.90, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\aa\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59027}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 32d2bddbe968d1f7f5a8a46714f28b56
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[@id='issuetype-single-select']//span[@class='icon aui-ss-icon noloading drop-menu']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:314)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:300)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:297)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    at com.nasa.testframework.helper.UtilClass.clickElement(UtilClass.java:34)
    at com.nasa.jira.pages.CreateIssuePage.clickIssueType(CreateIssuePage.java:124)
    at com.nasa.jira.stepDefinition.CreateIssuePageStepDefinition.userFillsOutTheAsterickFieldsOfStory(CreateIssuePageStepDefinition.java:47)
    at ✽.And User fills out the asterick fields of Story(src/test/java/com/nasa/jira/feature/jira.feature:42)
```

should be able to pass this test fine, but its throwing a no session Id after 2nd scenario starts.

Comment: How are you opening/closing your browser? Probably you need to make sure that it's starting a clean one.

Comment: Marit, I have a test base class where I have a AfterMethod with driver.close in it. @AfterMethod
 public void tearDown()
 {
  driver.close();
  log.info("Driver is closed");

 }

 public static WebDriver getDriver() {
  log.info("Driver is returned ");
  //System.out.println("TestBase - Inside getDriver method: "); 
  return driver;
 }
}

Comment: Ok, my next question would be whether the next time a browser is opened it is a "clean" one, or it reopens the one just closed.

Comment: I think it is opening the one that is just closed

Comment: Then find a way to open a clean one, or clear the session/cookies/whatever from the previous one. (Sorry, rusty on details, haven't front end automated in a while)